# WSO2 Micro Integrator and WSO2 Integration Studio license

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I have a question related to WSO2 Micro Integrator.

Reading what is reported in the open source distribution of the WSO2  Micro Integrator (https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator), which is released under the Apache license, I noticed that it is reported that "developers can create integrations graphically using WSO2 Integration Studio." This text is a link pointing to the tool on the WSO2 website (https://wso2.com/integration/integration-studio/)

To download the WSO2 Integration Studio tool from the WSO2 site, I had to accept the terms and conditions of the "WSO2 Software License" (https://wso2.com/licenses/eula/3.3).

Why does the documentation of the open source WSO2 Micro Integrator product (with apache license) link to a product on the WSO2 site with "WSO2 Software License" while it explains how to create integrations graphically? It should link to the open source version of this tool (i.e. https://github.com/wso2/integration-studio/releases/download/v8.2.0-rc2/WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.2.0-rc2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg) with apache license.

So my question is, using the open source version of:

- WSO2 Integration Studio
- WSO2 Micro Integrator

can I create a new product (sample.car) and commercialize it?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Integration Studio is the IDE used to develop integrations and deploy them to the MI runtime. You can use Integration Studio, downloaded from the website to do development, and it has no conflict with the Apache or EULA license.

License differences come to the picture when you are going to run the integration developed using Integration Studio. No matter which distribution of Integration Studio you used to develop the integrations, the production environment you are planning to deploy your integration should have either Apache or EULA license. Meaning if you are running MI distribution downloaded from GitHub, you don't need a commercial license for the product. But, if you are running the MI distribution downloaded from the website, then you need a WSO2 Subscription to run your integrations.

In short, when it comes to Integration Studio, the license does not matter. It matters when it comes to where you are running those developed integrations.